# Show results in two columns using presentation layer

Tags: wordpress, split

The function below lists the values ​​of a custom field in alphabetical order and without repetition. example:

- Alfred Hitchcock
- Frank Capra
- Pedro Almodóvar
- Woody Allen

How show these items in two columns? example:

[image]

Any tips? Grateful for any help.

The code:

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'director' ORDER BY meta_value";
$directors = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

echo '<ul>';
foreach( $directors as $director ) :

echo '<li>' . $director->meta_value . '</li>';

endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: this cannot be achieved using sql query result. Change your UI style to format data, ex - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different aspects of an application. Data is data, and its presentation is a view. You should not try to force the storage or retrieval of the data according to the way it is displayed. So get the data as you would for one column and display it into N columns using a presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks @srini.venigalla. That's exactly what I want to do. Any tips to get started?